# Join de tabelas para o Tableau

Tags: sql-server

Precisei criar uma extração para um relatório do Tableau, onde meu time desenvolveu o banco de dados e o sistema web e outra companhia desenvolveu o relatório do Table.

Esse é o esquema do problema
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para alimentar o relatório do tableau eu desenvolvi a solução abaixo, mas não sei se essa foi a melhor solução

```
DECLARE @Pillars table (Id int , Name varchar(30), ExhibitionOrder tinyint)
DECLARE @Initiatives table (Id int identity(100,2) , PillarId int,  Name varchar(35), ExhibitionOrder tinyint) 
DECLARE @Goals table (Id int identity(10,30) , PillarId int, Descriptions varchar(60), ExhibitionOrder tinyint) 

INSERT @Pillars (Id, Name, ExhibitionOrder) values 
 (1, 'Communication',1)
,(2, 'Environmental Responsibility',2)


INSERT @Initiatives (PillarId, Name, ExhibitionOrder) Values
(1,'Social Network',2)
,(1,'Television',1)
,(1,'Brand Content',3)
,(2,'Financial education',1)
,(2,'Your garbage, Your responsibility',0)

INSERT @Goals (PillarId, Descriptions , ExhibitionOrder) Values
 (1, 'Improves the number of direct contact on call center in 10%',2)
,(1, 'Reduces paper media in 2%',1)
,(2, 'Reduces in 35% the recycle garbage in the office',1)
,(2, 'Reduces in 2% the carbon footprint on the office',1)
,(2, 'Reduced 2% Hydro bill',1)


;WITH 
lv0(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   (VALUES (0), (0))G(n)), --2 
lv1(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b), -- 4 
lv2(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b), -- 16 
lv3(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b), -- 256 
lv4(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b), -- 65,536 
--lv5(N) as (select 0 from lv4  a cross join lv4 b), -- 4,294,967,296 
tally(n) AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM   lv4), 
t1 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY id ) N ,* FROM   @Pillars), 
t2 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY id ) N ,* FROM   @Initiatives), 
t3 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY id ) N ,* FROM   @Goals) 
SELECT  A.Name Pilar 
       ,b.Name Initiative 
       ,c.Descriptions Goals
       ,a.id 
       ,b.PillarId 
       ,c.PillarId 
FROM   tally t 
       CROSS JOIN t1 a 
       LEFT JOIN t2 b 
              ON t.n = b.n 
                 AND a.id = b.PillarId 
       LEFT JOIN t3 c 
              ON t.n = C.n 
                 AND a.id = c.PillarId 
WHERE  a.id IS NOT NULL 
       AND ( b.id IS NOT NULL 
              OR c.id IS NOT NULL ) 
ORDER  BY  IsNUll(a.ExhibitionOrder,255)
          ,IsNUll(b.ExhibitionOrder,255) 
          ,IsNUll(c.ExhibitionOrder,255)

            SELECT 
                    A.Name Pilar 
                   ,b.Name Initiative 
                   ,c.Descriptions Goals
                   ,a.id 
                   ,b.PillarId 
                   ,c.PillarId                 
            FROM
                @Pillars A
            INNER JOIN @Initiatives B
                ON
                A.Id = B.PillarId
            INNER JOIN @Goals C
                ON  
                A.Id = B.PillarId
            ORDER  BY  IsNUll(a.ExhibitionOrder,255)
                      ,IsNUll(b.ExhibitionOrder,255) 
                      ,IsNUll(c.ExhibitionOrder,255)
```

Resultado

```
Pilar                          Initiative                          Goals                                                        id          PillarId    PillarId
------------------------------ ----------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
Communication                  Television                          Reduces paper media in 2%                                    1           1           1
Communication                  Social Network                      Improves the number of direct contact on call center in 10%  1           1           1
Communication                  Brand Content                       NULL                                                         1           1           NULL
Environmental Responsibility   Your garbage, Your responsibility   Reduced 2% Hydro bill                                        2           2           2
Environmental Responsibility   Financial education                 Reduces in 2% the carbon footprint on the office             2           2           2
Environmental Responsibility   NULL                                Reduces in 35% the recycle garbage in the office             2           NULL        2

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: A coluna ExhibitionOrder é de preenchimento obrigatório? // Para um mesmo valor de PillarID, podem existir valores repetidos para a coluna ExhibitionOrder? // Se valores repetidos forem permitidos, como decidir qual é a ordem de exibição?

Comment: Olá @JoséDiz, o campo ExhibitionOrder é um campo opcional distinado para ordernar os registros na apresentação, ele pode possuir qualquer valor inteiro e não é unico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que a consulta pode ser montada com o uso de junção do tipo FULL OUTER JOIN entre as tabelas Initiatives e Goals, acrescentando sequenciamento por pilar em cada uma dessas duas tabelas.

```
-- código #1 v4
with 
cte_I as (
SELECT *, 
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by PillarId 
                               order by coalesce(ExhibitionOrder, Id))
  from @Initiatives
),  
cte_G as (          
SELECT *, 
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by PillarId 
                               order by coalesce(ExhibitionOrder, Id))
  from @Goals
)
SELECT coalesce(I.PillarId, G.PillarId) as PillarId,
       P.Name as Pilar,
       I.Name as Iniciativa, 
       G.Descriptions as Objetivo
  from cte_I as I 
       full outer join cte_G as G on I.PillarId = G.PillarId
                                     and I.Seq = G.Seq
       inner join @Pillars as P on P.Id = coalesce(I.PillarId, G.PillarId)
  order by P.ExhibitionOrder, coalesce(I.Seq, 255), coalesce(G.Seq, 255);
```

O sequenciamento por pilar é confiável nos casos em que a coluna ExhibitionOrder ou é informada para todas as linhas ou então para nenhuma linha de um mesmo pilar. Mas, se para um determinado valor de PillarId houver informação de ExhibitionOrder em somente parte das linhas, o sequenciamento por pilar pode (ou não) gerar ordem inesperada.

Answer (score 1):

Para as 3 tabelas existe o campo de ligação **PillarId**. Ou seja, uma hierarquia em 3 níveis. Mas o campo de ligação entre os 3 níveis é o mesmo. Então o resultado irá ser esse mesmo, muitas linhas, pois o resultado será retornar todos os registros da tabela 3 para cada PillarId da tabela 2 para cada ID da tabela 1. Neste caso, para o id 1 da tabela 1 existem 3 registros na tabela 2 e 2 registros na tabela 3, isso resultará em, 2 registros (tabela 3) para cada registro na tabela 2.

Para não ocorrer isso, é necessário haver um **outro campo de ligação** entre as tabelas 2 e 3.

Comment: As iniciativas podem ser para atender a um ou mais objetivos ou os objetivos podem ser alcançados por uma ou mais inicciativas. Representar essa abstração tornaria no sistema seria muito complexo uma vez que qualquer combinação acima é válida.